# greasemonkey adding onclick event to button

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am attaching onclick event on dynamically created button but the event is not firing.

```
var ind = location.href.indexOf('http://www.example.com/');
function init(){
    alert('h');
}
if(ind != -1){      
    var elem = document.createElement("input"); 
    elem.id ='btnGumb';
    elem.value = 'Select Check box';
    elem.type = 'button';
    elem.style.position = 'fixed';
    elem.style.left = '0px';
    elem.style.top = '0px';

    //this is not working
    elem.setAttribute('onclick', 'init();');

    //but alert is working:   elem.setAttribute('onclick', 'alert("h");');

    document.body.appendChild(elem); 

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

```
elem.addEventListener('click', init, false);
```

Your `init` function isn't defined on the content page window, so you can't set the function name as a string.

Comment: In your answer, what is the purpose of the "false" part?

Comment: @Rayz321, it has to do with whether to use capture or bubbling.  If you're not sure, you should generally use false/bubbling.  Newer browsers allow omitting that third parameter, but I don't recommend that currently.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked with GreaseMonkey, but I'm guessing your script is in its own scope and all its variables are released after the script finishes running.  Since you're defining init in this scope, but then calling it on the main page, the function is undefined when it's called.

You could put the entire function in the onclick event or trigger a callback:

```
if (elem.addEventListener) {
  elem.addEventListener('click',init,false);
} else {
  elem.attachEvent('onclick',init);
}
```

(attachEvent is IE-specific)